# Extract derived elements from a list of base elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have an interface list which stores a variety of objects derived from that interface.  I would like to write a function where the caller specifies the type to extract.  I've tried this:

```
List<IParts> PartList;
```

...

```
public List<IPart> Fetch(Type PartType)
{
   return this.PartList.OfType<PartType>().Cast<IPart>().ToList();
}
```

But it doesn't like a passed type.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to support various types at runtime (rather than at compile time with generics):

```
public List<IPart> Fetch(Type PartType)
{
    if (!typeof(IPart).IsAssignableFrom(PartType))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PartType", "Must derive from IPart");
    }
    return this.PartList.Where(i => i != null && PartType.IsAssignableFrom(i.GetType())).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Nice - certainly a bit simpler than using reflection to get the generic method. Probably more efficient for small lists and less efficient for large lists. You might want to check for nullity before calling i.GetType().

Comment: There I go assuming input is valid again. :)

Answer (score 2):

Specify it as a type parameter instead:

```
public List<IPart> Fetch<T>() where T : IPart
{
    return this.PartList.OfType<T>().Cast<IPart>().ToList();
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
List<IPart> foo = parts.Fetch<Exhaust>();
```

That's fine if you know the part type at compile-time. If you don't, you'll need to use reflection to basically get the `OfType()` method in `Enumerable<T>` and create the write generic method from it. Something like:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo OfTypeMethod = 
    typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("OfType");

public List<IPart> Fetch(Type partType)
{
    MethodInfo method = OfTypeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(partType);
    IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable) method.Invoke
        (null, new object[] { PartList });
    return enumerable.Cast<IPart>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: You can add a "where T : IPart" generic restriction that'll make it so you're not getting invalid casts and logic errors